# Fetch specific related models from a one-to-many relationship

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models Contact and Address. Contact has a one to many relationship to Address. There's a column "is_primary" on Address to indicate the main address for each Contact.

Now, I'd like to create a model manager to return a queryset with all Contact objects and the related Address object that has "is_primary=True". **The database should only be hit once.**

The goal is to use the queryset in a template and have the primary address together with the contact information in one record.

How can this be done?

Here's are the simplified models:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)

class Address(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    is_primary = models.Boolean()
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...
```

Comment: you could add @property attribute in Contact to return address with primary true

Comment: `Address.filter(is_primary=True).select_related('contact')`?

Comment: @PavanKumarTS: This is actually my current implementation, but it leads to a seperate database query for each Contact record. As I'm using this in a list view, it's extremely slow. That's why I have put the requirement "The database should be hit only once". I'm expecting the ORM to generate some sort of join query.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: I need to start from Contact as I have the same thing going on for various other related models, e.g. phone numbers, email addresses... I need to hit the database only once to be performant.

Comment: I think there's still a way with Pavan's solution if you use `select_related('address')` no? The related addresses will already have been fetched and a `primary_address` @property attribute can filter those out in python without making a new query. `next((address for address in self.address_set.all() if address.is_primary))` with some error handling for a StopIteration?

Comment: @Clepsyd: thanks for this, it could be a possible solution. Django would fetch too many addresses from the database tough, but as a contact has only a few addresses, this is probably not a big issue. I will give it a try. Maybe a raw sql query could be a solution too.